# onestepcheckout login popup css change from checkout page in magento

Tags: css, magento, checkout

I am having a problem with the onestepcheckout login popup, its working fine in normal browser in a computer but while trying to login using an iPhone the login popup gets hidden and cannot see it.
I tried to change the css and i find out that it has an inline css and what ever i try to put in there gets overwritten by the inline css, and i cannot seem to find how the inline css is being put in that block all i see is :

```
login_popup.phtml

<div id="onestepcheckout-login-popup" style="display: none;">
```

but when i see it in a firefox browser through a firebug it gives me

```
    <div id="onestepcheckout-login-popup" style="margin: 0px; position: absolute; z-index: 9999; top: 264px; left: 555px;">
```

I need to change the css so that it will be visible on the iPhone also , but i am having difficulty as i cannot find how the inline css is being put in there, anybody who encountered this problem with onestepcheckout or anybody, any suggestions or solutions will be greatly appreciated and thanked for.

Thank you

Comment: try contact support in case of issues with paid extensions

Comment: @Anton S : Thanks Anton i contacted the support , they replied onestepcheckout does not have mobile support, bummer.